# Perl regular expression with exception

Tags: regex, perl

For example I have strings "domain", "asset44.domain", "asset.domain", "domain1"

I need match with regular expression all strings where is "domain" word, but with some exception: I don't need match "asset44.domain" and "domain1".

First I did `if ($_ =~ /domain/io) {`
It's matching all strings

After I put `if ($_ =~ /domain(?!1)/io) {`
It's matching all string, except "domain1"

And now, I can't understand, how to except "asset44.domain", but keep in match "asset.domain".

P.S. asset44.domain there may be another number: asster56.domain for example.

**P.P.S
Solution:** `(?<!asset)(?<!\d\.)domain(?!1)`
https://regex101.com/r/sF2qG3/1

Comment: About the `/o` modifier, the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) says `o  - pretend to optimize your code, but actually introduce bugs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found how to do it better, this is my code.

```
(?<!asset)(?<!\d\.)domain(?!1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/sF2qG3/1

Thx for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Just some idea:

```
if ( $_ =~ /domain/ and (not $_ =~ /domain1/ or $_ =~ /asset44/) ){
   # do whatever
}
```

UPDATE:

```
 [^asset[0-9]domain[^domain1]
```

Here is a demo: [regex101.com/r/rJ4vC6/1](http://regex101.com/r/rJ4vC6/1)

Comment: This would be the approach I'd take - trying to build conditional logic like this in `regex` is at best, error prone and likely to be confusing to future readers. Where applying multiple tests is much clearer.

Comment: I forgot to tell, that "asse44.domain" can be "asset56.domain" for example. Random numbers.

And I don't like that AND/OR ... There must be a way that do it without AND/OR. But If I will not find better way, I will try your. Thx.

Comment: then you could try this: [^asset[0-9]domain[^domain1]    Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/rJ4vC6/1

Comment: There's probably a way to do it without a logic test - but it'll be unclear what the regex is doing, so it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\.)?domain$
```

We match an optional subdomain with `([a-zA-Z]+\.)?`
and string `domain`, with nothing behind it

See it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/sN6wH7/2)

Comment: Your example matching "asset" word in "asset.domain" and that's all.
But I need that match 2 strings of 4. It's "domain" and "asset.domain".

Comment: Do you mean that you need 2 results from the regex (see https://regex101.com/r/sN6wH7/3) ?

Comment: Sorry if my question was was not precise. Your regular good, but not good for string if there will me for example "Ninja was asset.domain and domain1", because in your code ^ and $.

I already found solution and thx again for your help.